# Azure DevOps pipeline how to assign variables to one pipeline that runs other pipelines with the same variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build an Azure DevOps pipeline that takes in 3-5 variables and runs a series of pipelines with those same variables passed through. Is it even possible or am I using variables incorrectly and I need to refactor the children pipelines to use parameters and somehow assign the variable to the parameter?

I have functional children pipelines that run when given variables. I tried to make a controller pipeline and pass the variables but they don't appear to actually be passing. My pipelines error out on empty variables.

Comment: If you were to put the core logic of the child pipelines into templates, you could call those templates from the main pipeline with the appropriate variables set.

Comment: (Also, if using templates, you could pass the variables as parameters to the template instead.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to pass variables between pipelines. You can try it instead invoke the pipeline from REST API and pass the value as a parameter.

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64749291/2347999) on this answer.

Bu please take a look also on a different aspect. Do you really need sperate pipelines? Maybe it should be done via multiple stages? Than you would be able to pass output parameters between stages.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of your variables would recommend leveraging either [Variable Groups] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) or [Variable templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#variable-reuse) if they are not secret values.

I would encourage variable templates first if you are leveraging YAML templates as this will put the variables under source control. The templates should be stored in a centralized repository which all the pipelines can access.

Variable groups is supported by both Classic and YAML Pipelines. You can edit who has access to update the variables; however, there is not "source control" on it. Just an audit when a value changes.